# How can I require a scala file from another directory to run a unit test?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm trying to run a unit test on my `Factorial` class, but I don't know how to include it in my `Test.scala` file.

Here is my `Factorial.scala` class:

```
class Factorial
{
    def recursive_factorial(number:Int) : Int = 
    {
        if (number == 1)
            return 1

        number * recursive_factorial (number - 1)
    }
}
```

And here is my `Test.scala`

```
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

class FactorialTest extends FlatSpec
{ 
    "recursive factorial function takes very large int" should "throw Stack  Overflow Exception" in
    {
        assertThrows[StackOverflowError]
        {
            factorial.recursive_factorial(100000)
        }
    }
}
```

`Factorial.scala` is in a folder (src) in `factorial/src` and `Test.scala` is in a folder in (test) in `factorial/test`.

How can I require my function from another file?

Comment: You can see the answer given by @Richeek, that is right. I'm not sure if your using an IDE, but if you don't, you will have to add the import statement as well (that depends on your package structure - I would guess it would be: import factorial.src.Factorial). A hint for your next developments - start always the class name with uppercase and check the camelCase practice for name conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your problem correctly, do you want to create an instance of `Factorial` class?

If so, its simple:

```
val factorial = new Factorial
factorial.recursive_factorial(100000)
```